# Get equal and unique identifier for 2 apps installed in the same iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, ionic-framework

I have two apps for iOS, one made with Swift and another with Ionic3, I need an unique and equal identifier for both of them. The Ionic app has user authentification but the other one doesn't have anything, just sends data to an API with the UDID (code below), so in the API if both identifiers are the same the data is saved. It's weird, I know, but this is a legacy code that I can't refactor.

In the native one I have this UDID:

```
NSString* udid = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

In Ionic3 I have `@ionic-native/unique-device-id` and `@ionic-native/device` but the UDID returned are always different. When user logs in the Ionic app it updates the UDID field in the database.

They need to send the same identifier even after reinstall them. How can I achieve that with minimal changes or without touching the native app.

Maybe it's possible to get anothers app UDID from Ionic3? Or from some kind of common storage between the two apps. Since the Ionic app needs to check if the other app is installed I'm also using URI Scheme.

Comment: create only 1 identifier and save it to keychain, so another app can use it

Comment: @canister_exister can you elaborate and make it an answer please? How do I create a Keychain in Objetive-c? Reading on the Ionic plugin looks like I need to create the container before reading the value, I guess I can't read the keychain of the native app.